Did Wikipedia spend $50m USD on diversity, equity, and inclusion (DEI) initiatives over the 2023-24 fiscal year?
The Libs of TikTok X account posted a snippet of "Wikipedia’s annual budget report from 2023—2024" as seen below.

They make the claim:

they spent over $50 million of their total $177 million budget on Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion

From the table in the graph it seems to me that this claim would include 'equity' as well as 'safety & inclusion'.
Did Wikipedia spend $50m USD on diversity, equity, and inclusion (DEI) indicatives over the 2023-24 fiscal year?
If so, out of academic interest, does anyone know what they were?

Here is the source they seem to be using. Pedantic point: The claim is about what was spent, while the source (a budget) is about what they planned to spend. Do you care whether they succeeded in spending that much, or is the fact they planned it enough?

@Oddthinking I think allocation is enough given the nature of the claim. Of course if they did indeed go significantly under, that would merit notice.

What does DEI mean here in the claim? Like what would "spending money on DEI" be?

@CJR: That is a reasonable question, but the OP doesn't get to define it. We should look to the context of the claim so we can see the claimant's definition and look for common use of the term.

DEI does stand for Diversity, Equity, and Inclusion so it would be accurate to include the section for that in the claim.

The Wikipedia definition doesn't appear to be the definition in the claim, looking at the replies (many of which mention "diversity of thought" and "woke left wing bias" and "anti-white racism")

What are "grants" and "movement support"? I could see it as being anything from "giving money to researchers in underrepresented countries to write articles about topics that are not currently present" to "general donations to the Movement for Black Lives."

Deleted poisoning-the-well comments.

The answer is almost certainly yes; what exactly it means to spend $50 million on DEI and whether it's good or bad are extremely subjective.
For one thing, the "Effectiveness" category on this pie chart includes programs that Wikimedia itself calls DEI: "Employee Resource Groups (ERGs) [which] are voluntary, staff-led groups whose aim is to foster a welcoming, diverse, equitable and inclusive workplace". If Libs of TikTok is claiming that "Equity" and "Safety & Inclusion" are all DEI just based on the category labels, then "Effectiveness" is DEI as well so it's up to $90 million worth of DEI. Without having to break down the numbers further, $50 million doesn't seem unreasonable.
The purpose of "DEI" for Wikipedia is obvious. The encyclopedia has no shortage of people with free time to contribute Star Trek episode summaries, but huge gaps in its coverage of topics in the developing world; furthermore, there are limited reliable sources available for such topics, so there are going to be systemic issues with bias. (Famously, early on in Wikipedia's history its founder Jimmy Wales attempted to add an article about a famous South African restaurant only to create a bitter edit war over the difficulty in finding reliable online sources about it.) Wikimedia's activities are generally about nurturing editing communities worldwide and overcoming systemic bias and disinformation.
Also, Wikimedia is bigger than Wikipedia. For instance, Wikimedia gave $20,000 to Northeast Indian entomologists to upload freely licensed photos of butterflies. And now we have 15,000 libre butterfly images.
Wikimedia's corporate structure is often criticized as wasteful and bureaucratic. However, their mission statement is clear: they attempt to accumulate media (on Wikimedia Commons), archive knowledge (on Wikisource), and summarize it all (on Wikipedia) on every language in which people are willing to contribute.  All the letters of "DEI" apply to the main problems they are trying to solve, so the fact that a lot of their spending is either self-described DEI or could be labeled as DEI is unsurprising.

"Safety & Inclusion" mostly isn't DEI-related.  It's mostly about protecting Wikipedia against legal changes, and protecting individual volunteers from lawsuits.

maybe the point of your 'understanding of DEI initiatives may not be their understanding of DEI initiatives/investments' could do with a bit more highlighting in the heading TLDR summary, as it imho is a major caveat on whether this answer "supports" the headlines being thrown around atm or not.

The context this answer provides is quite good.

@Mark, I'd love to see your comment about the "Safety & Inclusion" budget category sourced and expanded into another answer! I don't know where to start looking for a further breakdown of that category.

Good answer. One point of clarification: The WMF, generally speaking, does not employ people who directly edit Wikipedia (with extremely rare exceptions). They do a lot of outreach, workshops, etc., but the wiki is not written by them or their employees. The mention of "safety" is also suggestive of the T&S team, which does things that look a little more like traditional moderation.

"We need more articles on underrepresented parts of the world" seems to be the same statement as "we'd like to sell more products overseas," yet we would not call the latter a DEI initiative. Can you explain why you just accept the claim that Equity in the budget is a part of DEI as it's understood, when Wikipedia itself explains it as increasing coverage in other nations?
